# Data representations for speech data

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-processing

I'm interesting in knowing more about different kinds of data representations that are used for speech data. I know of FFT, but not any others. More precisely, I have the 3 following questions.

1. What data representations for speech data?
2. What is considered the most 'raw' representation?
3. How has the use of different representations evolved over time?

Simply answering 1 or 2 of the questions would also be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen people use MFCC coefficients for speech related analysis.It is a  done using filter banks and logarithmic scales for representing speech.